# How to check if an array has two different pairs of matching values?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static boolean hasTwoPair(int[] arrayOfInts){    
}
```

The method is supposed to return true if it can find two different pairs of matching `int` values. So if the array was `{2,2,4,7,7}`, it should return true because it has two 2s and two 7s.

It only applies to different pair values though. If it was `{2,2,2,2,5}`, it would return false because they are not different pair values.

EDIT: This is what I have so far for the body of the method:

```
     boolean pairFound = false;
    int pairValue;

    for(int s = 0; s < arrayOfInts.length - 1; s++){
        pairValue = arrayOfInts[s];

        for(int c = s + 1; c < arrayOfInts.length; c++){
            if(pairValue == arrayOfInts[c])
                pairFound = true;
        }
    }

    return false; //placeholder
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Should the pairs appear consecutive? I mean will the function return true for `{2,4,2,4,7}`?

Comment: @unlimit They do NOT have to be consecutive. The method should return true if it took in that array

Comment: @PerniciousRage And if there are more than two pairs? Will the function return true too?

Comment: @unlimit Most likely, the array will always contain 5 elements.  I bet this is related to cards...

Comment: @PerniciousRage I'll update my answer in a second.  You're almost there.

Comment: Fixing your code will be very tricky. On top of that, it is rather inefficient. Consider changing the approach to using per-value counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't actually tried any code, I'll give a description of how to solve this problem, but no actual code.

Start with a `boolean` like `pairFound` that's initialized to `false` and change to `true` when you find your first `pair`.  Additionally, you'll need an `int` (`pairValue` to keep track of the value of the first pair found (if you found one).

Iterate through, looking for a pair.  If you find a pair, and `pairFound` is false, set `pairFound` to `true`, and set `pairValue` to the value of your first found `pair`.  Now keep iterating through.

If you find a pair and `pairFound` is `true` and the pair is `!= pairValue`, then `return true;`.  If you iterate through everything and haven't returned `true` yet, then you can `return false`.

---

Based on your updated question, you're pretty close.

```
boolean pairFound = false;
int pairValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  
//or some value that arrayOfInts will never have based on context

for(int s = 0; s < arrayOfInts.length - 1; s++){
    if(arrayOfInts[s] == pairValue) { 
        continue; 
    }
    for(int c = s + 1; c < arrayOfInts.length; c++){
        if(arrayOfInts[s] == arrayOfInts[c]) {
            if(arrayOfInts[s] != pairValue) {
                if(pairFound) {    
                    return true;
                }
                pairValue = arrayOfInts[s];
                pairFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it went!

Comment: _"Iterate through, looking for a pair"_ -- That's pretty vague, unless one assumes that the array is sorted.

Comment: @TedHopp I left my answer pretty intentionally vague.  He put literally no effort into trying to solve this on his own, so I'm not going to put much effort into my answer.  My question is a good explanation of how to go about tackling the problem.  If he comes back with some specific problems/questions, he can get some more descriptive answers.

Comment: I added what I have so far.

Comment: This is not enough - you would need to store the value that you used for the first pair, in order to not use it again for the second pair. Otherwise, the code would produce false positives.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yea, I realized that pretty quickly, updated the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to add "pairFound = True" after the second if-statement? (arrayOfInts[s] == arrayOfInts[c])

Answer (score 2):

This task asks you to build a list of counts:

- Create a data structure (say, a `Map<Integer,Integer>`) containing a count for each number from the array.
- Go through the map, and count the number of entries with the count of two and above.
- If you counted two or more items, return `true`; otherwise, return `false`.

The counts for your first example would look like this:

```
V   #
-   -
2 - 2
4 - 1
7 - 2
```

You have two items (2 and 7) with counts of 2, so return `true`.

The counts for your second example look like this:

```
V   #
-   -
2 - 4
5 - 1
```

There is only one item with the count above 2, so return `false`.

If you use a `HashMap`, this algorithm produces an answer in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array. Then look for the first two consecutive values that match. If found, skip to the first entry that is different from the matched pair and repeat. If you reach the end of the array before either the first or second search succeeds, return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort the array, that would give O(n*log(n)) complexity. But your current solution is even worse since it's yielding O(n^2) complexity. But you also don't need a HashMap. A Set and an integer is enough:

- For each array element do

  - Check: is the element already in the set?

    - If not put it into the set
    - If yes check if it's equal to your last found Int pair (yes, use a boxed Int, not a primitive int here, to be able to initialize it with `null`)

      - If it's equal continue
      - If it's not equal

        - If the last found pair is `null` set it to elements value
        - Otherwise you're done and you have at least 2 different pairs
- If you iterated over the list without reaching the last condition you don't have 2 different pairs

As for the Set implementation I would recommend a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

There is more to say here though. If you implement it like this you make no assumption about integers and indexable arrays. All you need is a list of comparable elements.  So you could make the signature of your method much more generic:

```
public static boolean hasTwoPair(Iterable<E> iterable)
```

But since arrays don't support generics and the Iterable interface every client of this method would have to transform Array parameters to an Iterable with the `asList()` method. If that's too inconvenient you can provide another method:

```
public static <T> boolean hasTwoPair(T[] array)
```

In general it's a good idea to use the most generic type possible when you design API's (also see Item 40 and 52 in "Effective Java, Second Edition")